# How to map dynamic jackson parameters with POJO class at Deserialization?

Tags: java, json, hibernate, spring-mvc, jackson

EDIT: I want to map the jackson object with POJO java class dynamically at the time of deserialization.

> Eg. {id:1,name:"rajeev", phone:"5555"}

POJO class

```
class Data{
    public int id;
    public string name;
    public string contact;
}
```

The above jackson object must mapping with existing POJO class without any error. Here phone is the optional parameter

Comment: I did not understand your question well can you add more details

Comment: which parameters are dynamic ? can you give an example ?

Answer (score 0):

if you work with spring mvc this an exemple

```
@Controller
public class YourJSONController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/YourUri", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Data getDataInJSON() {

        Data data= new Data();
        //setter

        return data;

    }

}
```

and dont forget to add jackson data bind dependency to your pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that the json response attributs name may be different from your attributs name, you can use the annotation `@SerializedName("ZIPNAME")` of package `com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName`.

For example, your classe may look like :

```
class Data{
public int id;
public string name;
@SerializedName("phone")
public string contact;
}
```